# The difference between g++ and clang++'s handling of VLAs definition and initialization in c++

Tags: c++, variable-length-array

The source code as follows：

```
using namespace std;

int main()
{
        int m = 4;
        int arr[m] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
        printf("%d\n", arr[2]);
        return 0;
}
```

When I compile with **g++**, it compiles successfully as an executable. But when I compile with **clang++**, I get the following error：

```
VLAs.cpp:8:10: error: variable-sized object may not be initialized
        int arr[m] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
                ^
1 error generated.
```

After testing, I found that clang ++ can support the definition of VLBs（`int arr[m]；`）, but does not support defining VLBs while initializing them. I would like to know the root cause of this difference

Comment: If you're going to initialize `arr` at the point where you declare it, why don't let the compiler deduce its size? `int arr[] = {1,2,3,4};`

Comment: VLAs are a compiler extension and not part of the language. I assume that gives the compiler writers full freedom in how and what they want to support in regards to it. I doubt there is any meaningful answer here.

Comment: VLAs in standard C can't be initialized and I assume clang++ just took that as-is when adding this extension to C++

Comment: Side question: What are VLBs? What does the B stand for?

Comment: The fact that you have both `using namespace std;` and `printf`, and you're using variable length arrays makes me really question whether you realize that C++ is not a perfect superset of C.

Comment: The real question is why get hung op on some non-standard extension of C++. VLA != C++. For run-time sized arrays there is std::vector

Comment: @TedLyngmo • VESA Local Bus (VLB).

Comment: @Eljay  Now, that's something I haven't heard about in many years :-)

Answer (score 0):

VLAs are not C++ and compiler support them differently. In C initializing VLAs is not supported and that seems to be what clang does in c++ as well. gcc on the other hand has extended the support for VLAs a bit. Your next compiler might not have VLAs at all.

So why bother if C++ has far superior mechanisms for this:

```
#include <vector>
#include <array>

constexpr int n = 4;
std::array arr{1, 2, 3, 4};
std::array<int, n> arr2 = {1, 2, 3, 4};
std::vector<int> arr3 = {1, 2, 3, 4};
```